# Java - If statement not working (comparing strings)

Tags: java, string, if-statement, compare

When I grab the IP Address from my open socket, as someone has sent me a stream, I noticed that the IP has a forward-slash.

I just plan to simply omit it.  But first I want to validate the first character in the string is the forward-slash:

```
String dataSource = data.getAddress().toString();

if(dataSource.substring(0,1) == "/"){
    System.out.println("trailing forward slash, delete it ");  
    dataSource = dataSource.substring(1);
}
```

This IF statement isn't being detected.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `.equals` to compare the content. `==` always compare by reference.

Comment: @nhahtdh That is true. However, he is obviously a beginner(no offense) and there is no reason to downrate him for this. I counter with an upvote.

Comment: legitamate question, ameture yes, but not a silly question and was worded correctly.

Comment: @Sean F yeah, he is trying. I have been in his shoes before with stuff like this.

Comment: Take a look at comparing references vs primitive data types (Srinivas B has a good point). After you get that, take a look at string object pooling and interning just to confuse yourself a little bit! ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string comparisons use `equals` method, as it is more reliable than using `==` operator (it compares the content while `==` comnpares the references ) :

Try using `equals` method :

```
if(dataSource.substring(0,1).equals("/")){
```

Answer (score 2):

please use .equals

```
if("/".equals(dataSource.substring(0,1))){
    System.out.println("trailing forward slash, delete it ");  
    dataSource = dataSource.substring(1);
}
```

instead of ==

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test only, the first character , you can try the method,

**dataSource.charAt(0)=='/'**

Answer (score 1):

you should use `.equals` for string comparrisons
 so

```
if(dataSource.substring(0,1) == "/")
```

should be

```
if ("/".equals(dataSource.substring(0,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings with `==`, which means you're checking to see if these two strings are literally the same string reference.

Use `equal()` to check and see if two strings contain the same characters.

See: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals(Object)` or `.equalsIgnoreCase(String)` for comparing Strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `dataSource.substring(0,1).equals("/")`, which actually checks the content of the strings. `==` only checks whether both sides are the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if (("some string to check").equals(myString)){
  doSomething();
}

Answer (score 0):

Always use `equals` when comparing values. Having said that you can just use `indexOf` method for your purpose

```
   if (dataSource.indexOf('/') == 0) {
        dataSource = dataSource.substring(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String dataSource = "/hell";

        if(dataSource.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("/")){
            System.out.println("trailing forward slash, delete it ");  
            dataSource = dataSource.substring(1);
        }
```

run this program. this is working..

Answer (score 0):

Why use a String? You're just creating this problem for yourself. Use the datatype provided:

```
InetAddress dataSource = data.getInetAddress();
```

or

```
SocketAddress dataSource = data.getRemoteSocketAddress();
```

Then you have a semantically-aware `.equals()` method in both cases.